# How should I handle persistence for referenced entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, domain-driven-design

I'am using Entity-Framework and DDD.

If I have a reference between two entities, how should I handle persistence?  Do updates cascade?

Suppose an Employer has reference to their Manager directly.

If I change the Employee.Manager.Name, and save the Employee, does the Manager’s Name get changed?

Comment: You should not modify multiple aggregate roots in a single transaction. Favor reference by identity rather than object reference: it will help avoiding such mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a DDD point of view, any link to a `Manager` from an `Employee` should be by referencing the id only (assuming that `Managers` are not part of the `Employee` aggregate root and that `Manager` is an aggregate root in its own right).

Essentially your property `Employee.ManagerId` should return an id that allows you to retrieve the `Manager` for that `Employee`.

This will go against a lot of the 'goodness' that you get out of the box with Entity Framework, but this is usual for DDD.  It's recommended to design your domain model around the business domain and not your database implementation.

Personally, I find that using EF entities as my domain model doesn't fit well when I'm practising DDD.  Things like lazy loading navigation properties contradict good DDD practice.  I tend to use document databases in my own projects these days, but when I have to use SQL, I restrict the EF entities to my persistence layer and code my repositories to return non-EF entities from my domain model instead.

Comment: Excellent answer. EF is amazing for CRUD but needs to be used with care when persisting domain driven design entities

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips I tend to agree if the two entities are both Aggregate Roots, which the OP didn't specify. I would also be more nuanced than you regarding EF entities / Domain entities. "Most people who practice DDD" seems a bit like a blanket statement here.

Comment: @guillaume31 I guess it is, I'll reword it.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips and what about optimizing the performance?

I mean, in this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27502014/967124 @marianoc84 talks about a possible ValueObject that in the case of this question could be `EmployeeManager` which would contain the `ManagerId` and the `name` of the `Manager` (let suppose we only need this attribute when we obtain a list of employees.

This way, we won't need another query in order to obtain the name of the `Manager` based on the `ManagerId`.
BTW, I don't know if that is a good design decision because of the multiple drawbacks. Opinion?

Comment: @marianoc84s answer is a bit unclear, if they are advocating one AR (aggregate root) holding an object reference to another AR, then that doesn't sound very DDD.  If however they're referring to a reference by id, then that is fine.  Personally if the extra hit to get a manager was that costly, I'd data cache it somehow using something like AppFabric, Memcached, Redis, etc.  I cannot think of when I would need to load many employees and their managers all in one.  If this requirement came up for reporting purposes then I would get the data out of a separate reporting database.

Comment: I get your point @AdrianThompsonPhillips. BTW, I was trying to put an example with the `Employee` and `Manager` of a more complex problem. For example: Suppose you have a list of `Order` made by the `Employee`, the `City` where this `Employee` lives, his/her associated `Role` in the company and so on. You will end up referencing all those data by the value objects of their identifiers and doing all the "simulated joins" in the `EmployeesList` Domain Service.
Despite being possible to cache it, it sounds quite strange. I understood it well?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the usual setup where your application uses one DbContext:

Yes, it will also save the referenced entity.

At the moment you set the Manager name, it will load the Manager reference and keep track of it. When you save changes by calling [`DbContext.SaveChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx), it will commit all changes made to objects the `DbContext` is keeping track off.

The only option to not have this behaviour is by using multiple `DbContext` instances, but this opens a host of other problems (For instance: they are not aware of each others changes).